# is there any workaround for viewing different admin template according to user role

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, templates, joomla-3.5

This will work like e.g. If user is having super administrator access level, then user will be redirected on the default **Isis** administrator template. But if user is having access of administrator level or any other like manager, then the user will be redirect on **Hathor** administrator template.

is there any workaround for it?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this simple steps:

- Go to **Users** > **Manage**, from here select your user.
- Inside you can can see a Tab called **Basic Settings**, change the template for each user
   in the field **Backend Template Style**.

[image]

At the time we don't have this feature for user groups by default, so we can't automate it a little more, if you have few users use the above process.

If you have many users and you need this feature try with one extension like:

- [Advanced Template Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/style-a-design/templating/advanced-template-manager)